# Почему не работает такое ветвление?

Tags: c, if

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

main()
{
while (1)
{
printf("Введите сумму: ");
float A;
scanf("&g",&A);
 if ( A > 100 )
 printf ( "У Вас очень много денег\n" );
 else if (A>10 || A=100)
 printf ( "У Вас достаточно денег\n" );
else
 printf ( "У Вас маловато денег\n" ); 
getch();
}
}
```

Выдаётся ошибка:
 *lvalue required as left operand of assignment*

Comment: Для начала у вас ошибка в условии: `A == 100`, а не `A = 100`

Comment: Спасибо (забыл)!

Comment: Что такое `"&g"` в `scanf`???

Comment: Да, уже исправил. (Но та ошибка выдавалась именно из-за ==).

Comment: @Олег Остапчук: Нет. Ваше `==` не имеет никакого значения, пока в переменной `A` содержится мусор. Поэтому  `==` - дело десятое. Ошибка - именно бред в `scanf`. Так в чем вопрос-то теперь?

Comment: @AnT Да всё работает давно)